# How to layout for a CSS web directory in a web project

Tags: jsp, css, web

Right now, I want to make a web page interface can be obtained from a number of other sites such as translate.google.com or bbc.com. I use firebug to get the css distribution (css class, div) of elements in the page (such as button, the div, the textbox ...)

However, at present I only save css for pages to only a file named index.css. This storage way caused many difficulties for me when the number of css classes are quite large and they are taken from multiple pages and especially when I want to find the css in specific page (for example, when I want to find a css for the button from google). When design  for other web project, I can not reuse the css here.

I look forward to seeing some method  of layout css directory of smart people who have the experiences to find a method that allows re-use css in another web project.

I'm developing web with JSP, using  JSF 2.0 framework and NetBeans 7.1.2 editor.

Thank you for viewing my question

Answer (score 0):

I usually divide my web app into several files, for example navbar.jsp, header.jsp, footer.jsp, each of them links to their specific css file: navbar.css, header.css and footer.css. Then in every page you include these jsp files.

I'm not sure whether this is the standard way but I think it worked my apps. Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh thank you so much about your answer.

I've tried this way in my previous project, but unfortunately I can't use this when I want to know specifically about the css of another website where I takes CSS from (ex google, bbc.com...)